# How to merge hard disks in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, webmin, virtualmin

I have a web server working very well which currently is using one hard disk of 2TB, but this same server have another 2TB hard disk without any function so i want to partionate it in order to merge them to make 4TB memory space on my server, is there a way to do something like this? I'm using Ubuntu Server 18 with `webmin` and `virtualmin`.

[image]

> I'm really noob in linux doing this kind of things, so i'll really appreciate you tell me step by step an example in order to get my goal.

Thanks

Comment: you need to use lvm and create a logical volume.

Comment: I agree with c4f4t0r, here are more detailed instructions answered in another post in: [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219881/how-can-i-create-one-logical-volume-over-two-disks-using-lvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create either a software RAID, or an LVM logical volume spanning two disks. Notice that by simply aggregating the disks, you also aggregate the chances of failure: once your disks are grouped in a virtual 4 TB drive, if either of these fails you'll lose everything.

From your `lsblk` output, we see that your sdb drive is in use (as the system drive). Therefore you can't aggregate it to the other drive: you can only aggregate unused disks or partitions.

So your only option is to partition your `/dev/sda`, make a filesystem on it, and mount it somewhere like `/mnt`. All of this is easily done in Webmin from the "disk partition" tool in the "Hardware" subsection. Here is the way to do it from the command line:

```
# create the partition table (GPT)
sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt

#create a partition spanning the whole disk
sudo parted /dev/sda mkpart 1 ext4 1 -1

#create a filesystem on the new partition
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1

#create a mountpoint
sudo mkdir /mnt/disk

#mount the disk
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/disk

#edit /etc/fstab and add a line like this
/dev/sda1 /mnt/disk ext4 defaults 0 0
```